# Bootstrap background image appear on every page of my site

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

This is my code:

```
html, body {
      background: url("media/images/maishahotbgimg.jpg") repeat;
```

It only appears on the homepage. I want it to appear on every page of my web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a main.cs file that you will insert in all your HTML files. This si, you Can get all the html files having the same background image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single .css file linked in all your pages and apply the background in the css, for example:

```
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;  
  background-image: url(../../imagesfolder/backgroundexample.svg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

I tend to use a background color in case the img can't load properly (connectivity issues or whatsoever)